# Can't use methods of other class even after creating an object

Tags: java

There is also a public class with main method, but these class just wont let me call each others methods, variables into each other, same goes with using statements like switch/case. All requires to be inside method.

```
class bin{
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("You typed print.");
    }
}

class process{
    bin bn = new bin();
    bn.print();
    

}
```

It might work when I extend class but why it isn't working this way?

They work fine when I call it(method) inside a method of class 'process', but without creating a method I cant call methods of 'bin' class.

Comment: "without creating a method I cant call methods of 'bin' class" - without creating a method (or constructor, or instance initializer) you can't write *any* non-declaration statements. It's nothing to do with calling a method on an instance of a class - you'd get the same probelm if you wrote `System.out.println("This won't compile");` directly in the `process` class declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You can't put arbitrary code in a class and expect it to execute. `process` contains no methods. Class names should start with a capital letter. The typical entry point of a Java program is `main`. And you don't appear to have one of those. Finally, your classes *should* be in a package.

```
class Bin {
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("You typed print.");
    }
}

class Process {
    public static void main(String[] args) { // entry-point
        Bin bn = new Bin();
        bn.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding, I had main method in another class of this .java file. I just wanted to know why things are not working between these two classes. Lets assume its not a print method, its a method that returns a value, cant I call that method to get its value? and also switch statement wasnt working in process class.

Comment: @maulik: "I had main method in another class of this .java file" - so you mean the code you've shown us isn't the code that you're actually trying to fix? That's really unhelpful. The code you've shown us is broken in one way, as Elliott explained to you. If your *actual* code isn't broken in that way, but is broken in another way, how are we meant to be able to tell?

Comment: You can't put arbitrary code in the middle of a class. You *could* use something called an initialization block, but you need to be clear about when you expect this code to run (what should invoke it, how and when). That is why we place code in methods, to invoke it at a specific point in time.

Answer (score 0):

You missed adding a method:

```
class process{
    public void print() {
        bin bn = new bin();
        bn.print();
    }
}
```

Your code needs to be inside a method, except for data member declarations. As your code was, your second class had some code to be processed without being inside a method.